# How to reference a column by its name (eg. "someColumn")?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I reference, say column A, which is named "apple"? (see the first image) Most answers I have found on the internet seem to include a column name somewhere in the actual column (second picture) and use the find function or match function. However, I would much rather identify a column by its name, so I can, say, do something like Range("apple1:apple10").

[image: What I want]

[image: Not what I want]

As background for this, I am making an Excel sheet with a lot of macros for a company, but am leaving soon, and want to make this sheet as unbreakable and flexible as possible, so that users can change data within the sheet and even add or remove columns. They do not know VBA and do not have the time to change my code. However, if they add a column it will mess up my macro, which currently references cells like Cells(4,7), so if you add a column before column 7, stuff will be misreferenced.

An alternative solution I have thought about is monitoring when users add or remove columns, but this seems to be too much work, can introduce too many errors, and take too long, whereas referencing columns by their names, which I can enforce users do not change, would be much simpler.

Any ideas are great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used **named ranges** instead. These will shift if columns are inserted and remain valid.

For example A1:A7 has been named "Apple" here

[image: Apple]

If I insert a column before A:A then "Apple" will still refer to the same cells but now be B1:B7

---

In VBA you can access cells within this range. For example, the first cell in the "Apple" range:

```
Range("Apples").Cells(1,1)
```

These can be dynamic ranges, for example, to occupy only the populated part of a column, which is more efficient than setting for the entire column.

---

Read about named ranges [here.](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html)

Comment: You can reference the entire column by given it a Name as mentioned above. Just use A:A

Comment: Thanks, I did not know I could do that! Will accept your answer when my time limit is up

Comment: And yea @QHarr I know I was responding to another who seemed to have deleted their comment.

Comment: No worries. I saw the comments come and go :-)

Answer (score 1):

Turn your range into a table. Select any cell in your range:

[image: any one cell is selected inside the data range]

Then from the *Home* Ribbon, click *Format as Table* and pick any style.

[image: "Format as Table" dropdown]

Your table has headers, so tick that checkbox:

[image: "Format as Table" dialog]

Congratulations, you now have a *table* - you can rename it from the *Table Tools* Ribbon tab:

[image: Table1]

Now you can leverage the complete awesomeness of [*table formulas*](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) in Excel:

[image: table formula]

...and in VBA you get to work with the wonderful [`ListObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobject-object-excel) API: now `Sheet1.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange` gets you a `Range` reference that contains the entire *body* of the table, and best of all you never need to work out the last row with data anymore.

```
Dim myTable As ListObject
Set myTable = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
With myTable.ListColumns("Banana").DataBodyRange
    '...
End With
```

Comment: And another major advantage, at least for me, is that the table expands automatically as you add data, so the range names are dynamic without having to use the usual workarounds.

Comment: OK thank you very much I haven't used tables but this seems that it could really help me too.